# Free gives error

Tags: c, unix, malloc

Consider the following two programs:

```
/***************correct: no error for this code **************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

char  *p ,*q ;
p =(char *)malloc(10) ;
 strcpy( p , "AB") ;
*p = '\0' ;
p++ ;
q = p ;
//*q = 32 ;
free(q) ;
return 0;
}
/*************code2 which gives error ********************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

int  *p ,*q ;
p =(int  *)malloc(10) ;
*p = 30 ;
p++ ;
q = p ;
*q = 32 ;
free(q) ;
return 0;
}
```

Can you explain why the first one works, but the second doesn't?

Comment: `free()`ing anything not returned by `malloc()` is undefined behaviour in both those cases.  If one happens to work that is sheer luck and not something you should depend on.

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc`. Casting is, at best, redundant and (**as in your code**) may hide errors; *namely the failure to include the header where `malloc` is declared making the compiler assume the return type is `int` instead of `void*`.*

Comment: Although not an exactly great question, I don't believe it deserves a downvote. OP is clearly trying to understand how things work. When I started learning C, I too thought that calling free on `p+i` would free the memory starting from `p+i`. I really don't see anything criminal about this questino. **Free Question Downvotes Are Evil**

Answer (score 13):

The code that works "correct" has [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It's just (bad) luck that it works. Actually seeming to work is the worst that can happen as a result of UB(doesn't raise your alarm). The other code that doesn't work has undefined behavior as well.

You may call `free` ***only*** on pointer returned by `malloc`, `realloc` or `calloc`

Answer (score 1):

What the C standard says is that You cannot use free() for a normal pointers.It says free() function performs its action when it is used with the dynamic memory allocation functions like malloc(), calloc() and realloc().Even though if you try to use a free() by passing a normal pointer which is not involved with malloc(),calloc() and realloc(), it results undefined behaviour it may lead to core dumped error or crash and the code is working with your compiler because the compiler might be developed in a different way (example a student learning compiler) that code works even with the TURBO c but it really fails when you work on the cygwin or gcc compilers.I suggest you to work on cygwin and gcc compilers rather than other compilers because they give you very vast experience and knowledge even you can learn the concepts of Multithreading.

Comment: dont forget to accept an answer arpita.accept the one which makes you more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both the codes are incorrect and should end up with crash. As when you do `malloc` the OS keeps the initial address of the memory returned by `malloc` and `free` can only be called on the address given by `malloc`.

Comment: No, Undefined Behavior isn't necessarily a crash. It's undefined